# Ionic cordova vibration not working on Android 10

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I use the [Cordova plugin Vibration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-vibration). Following the example from the [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/vibration).

I have tested on several Android devices. Everything works fine with all Android in version < 10.

No device with Android 10 vibrate. There are no error neither warning. I don't understand what is the problem, I don't know in which direction to look.

Devices aren't mute.

I don't declare the `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission because the plugin already declares it. I have checked, the permission is present in the `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Edit: After more tests I realised that the vibration works fine in all pages of my application except the one where I need it. On this page I use another plugin, which can also emit vibrations [Scandit for Cordova](https://github.com/Scandit/scandit-cordova-datacapture-core). I wonder if there can't be conflicts between the two plugins.

Comment: Me too, it's not working :( and also FlashLight. But Geolocation is worked

Comment: @Bcktr I have updated my question. Do you use other plugins that can vibrate ?